# vhdl programming scale the value from 32 scale to 100 scale

Tags: hardware, vhdl

I have a six bit number(5 downto 0) output.Now the result of my program is from 32 (in binary 100000) .I have a result from 0 until 32 unsigned and i want to convert it to 0 until 100( in binary) 
for example the result 
DECIMAL

- 32 is 100
- 24 is 75
- 16 is 50
- 8 is 25
- 0 is 0

BINARY

- 100000 is 1100100
- 011000 is 1001011
- 010000 is 0110010
- 001000 is 0011001
- 000000 is 0000000

100,75,50,25,0 (all will be appear in binary) is what i want to do.
I want  to scale the entire range..but the main values are this.
I hope it is more clear now

Comment: This question is not clear at all, and needs to be significantly reworded. It would help to show us **exactly** the output you are expecting for a given input, rather than saying "like this, but in binary".

Comment: A bit more clear - do you want to scale the entire range of values, or only convert those specific values?

Comment: I understand your question a bit better. Do you have any code or specific error messages you can share with us? Have you attempted to accomplish this yet?

Comment: And really what you seem to want is not exactly converting a 6-bit value to a 7-bit value (since there's no conversion, per se, in just extending the length), but scaling a value from one range to another.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking to scale your input by some scale factor.  In this case, the scale factor is fixed.  Do you really want to go from 0-32?  Or from 0-31?  I'll assume the total range is 0-31 and you're mapping that from 0-99.

Original Range:  32

Scaled Up Range: 100

Scale Factor:    100/32 = 3.125

Multiply your input binary value by 3.125 and you'll have your output value.

Comment: How i can do this in structural? No the range is from 0 until 32 and yes i want to scale the value from 32 scale  to 100 scale

Comment: Instantiate a multiplier and make one input constant. Do you mean behavioral?

Comment: well it is better structural but if there is no other way then in behavioral

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to a hardware multiplier, is to make a hardware mapping table, which is feasible for few and short values as in this case.  The code for a mapping table may be:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity mdl is
  port(
    a_i : in  std_logic_vector(6 - 1 downto 0);
    z_o : out std_logic_vector(7 - 1 downto 0));
end entity;


library ieee;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
architecture syn of mdl is
begin

  process (a_i) is

    type mapping_t is array (0 to 32) of std_logic_vector(z_o'range);

    function mapping_fun return mapping_t is
      variable res_v : mapping_t;
    begin
      for i in 0 to 32 loop
        res_v(i) := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i * 100 / 32, z_o'length));
      end loop;
      return res_v;
    end function;

    constant mapping : mapping_t := mapping_fun;

  begin
    z_o <= mapping(to_integer(unsigned(a_i)));
  end process;

end architecture;
```

The synthesis tool is usually able to optimize a constant mapping table (as the here) pretty effectively, and the above only takes 6 ALMs in Altera.

The table approach is in special a good solution, if the conversion factor is not as nice as `25 / 2^3`, as in this case.

Comment: this will work for every number from the scale of 32 ? the unsigned number 15 it will show the number 46?

Comment: write a testbench and run through all of those calculations on your own!

Comment: Its supposed to... but as Russell says; best way to find out is to write a test bench and simply try all the values ;-)